# Discrete probability and random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

for $i \in \{ 1, 2 \}$, let $\Omega_i \subset \mathbb{R}$, let $\mathbb{P}_i$ be a discrete probability function on $\Omega_i$ and let $X_{i}: \Omega_i \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the identity function, $X_i \left( \omega \right) = \omega$ for every $\omega \in \Omega_i$.
Show that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are equally distributed iff there exists a finite or a countable subset $S \subset \Omega_1 \cap \Omega_2$ such that $S = Supp \left( \mathbb{P}_1 \right) = Supp \left( \mathbb{P}_2 \right)$ and $\mathbb{P}_1 \left( x \right) = \mathbb{P}_2 \left( x \right)$ for every $x \in S$.
So in the first direction, I thought about defining $S = \{ x \in \Omega_1 \cap \Omega_2  : X_1 \left( x \right) = X_2 \left( x \right) = x = a\} \subset \Omega_1 \cap \Omega_2$, for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$, and it indeed works when I want to show that $\mathbb{P}_1 \left( x \right) = \mathbb{P}_2 \left( x \right)$ for every $x \in S$, Directly from the definition of $S$ and by the fact that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are equally distributed. But I wasn't able to show that $S = Supp \left( \mathbb{P}_1 \right) = Supp \left( \mathbb{P}_2 \right)$.
If anyone could help me out with it I would be glad.

Comment: Rather take $S = Supp \left( \mathbb{P}_1 \right)$ and use that $X_1,X_2$ are equally distributed fo prove the remaining properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume that $\Omega_i \subset \mathbf{R}$ are two sets ($i = 1,2$) with corresponding probability measures $\mathbf{P}_i$ on them, which are assumed discrete (i.e. there exists a countable set $D$ such that $\mathbf{P}(D^\complement) = 0$). Let $X_i$ denote the identity function restricted on $\Omega_i,$ for $i = 1,2.$

**Claim:** A necessary and sufficient condition for $\mathbf{P}_1 = \mathbf{P}_2$ on $\Omega_1 \cap \Omega_2$ and that this intersection has mass 1 is that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are identically distributed.

This claim is rather a tautology due to some tacit assumptions. A random variable necessarily is defined on a probability space (if it is just defined on a measurable space, it would be called a measurable function; not random variable). Therefore, it is assumed tacitly that $X_i$ is defined on $(\Omega_i, \mathscr{P}(\Omega_i), \mathbf{P}_i)$ and since $X_i$ is just the identity, then $\mathbf{P}_i(X_i = t) = \mathbf{P}_i(\{t\})$ and the result follows at once: the left hand side is, by definition, the mass function of $X_i;$ if the $X_i$ have the same distribution, then $\mathbf{P}_1 = \mathbf{P}_2$ on the intersection which necessarily have full mass (i.e. the complement is a null set), and if the $\mathbf{P}_i$ are equal on the intersection which has mass 1, then the $X_i$ have the same distribution by definition again.

If you want to "extract" the support, all being discrete, simply consider
$$
\mathrm{spt}(X_i) = \{t \mid \mathbf{P}_i(X_i = t) > 0\} = \{t \mid \mathbf{P}_i(\{t\}) > 0\} = \mathrm{spt}(\mathbf{P}_i).
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, I understood and managed to prove it